# How to use an Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('application:main') result

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

As the title say, I have some problem understanding what does this call return.
This is how I am using it:

```
fetchEngines()
    {
        let object = Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('application:main').engines;
        console.log(object);
    }
```

And it return me something like that:
[image: example]

At this point, this is what I want, the list of all my [ember-engines](https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-engines).
 But I don't know how to use it. By that I mean, how do I fetch the name of each engine, what is `object` at this point, I can't find anything about it.

I have tried the `forEach()` method, but it returns me : `object.forEach is not a function`. I have also tried the `Object.keys` method, but it returned me undefined, maybe somebody can indicate me a doc or something, I don't understand at all what is it.
Good day to you and thank you for reading.

Comment: I guess it is Ember's empty object. [Look at here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.7.0/packages/ember-metal/lib/empty_object.js) for an older code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this. This is very simple, and I made a mistake. The `Object.keys` method work, I didn't know how to write it well.

This is the corrected version:

```
fetchEngines()
    {
        let object = Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('application:main').engines;
        // This will properly show every key in your object
        console.log(Object.keys(object));
        // And if you want to enumerate it
        let filledArray = [];
        for (let key in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key))
                filledArray.push(key);
        }
        // The object filledArray is now a perfectly manipulable object
    }
```